# pass data from database in httpresponse redirect

Tags: django, forms, redirect

Am new to django framework,am just trying to create seperate login form other than administrator login.I need to authenticate a user using username and password, fetch the details of that user from database and pass that data  to a templae (home page) to display it.

My code is as follows:-

view.py:-

```
def login_user(request):
user = ''
passw = ''
username1 = ''

if request.POST:
    user = request.POST.get('username')
    passw = request.POST.get('password')
    #password1 = ''
    try:
        userdata = Employee.objects.get(username = user, password = passw)
        user_id = request.session["user_id"] = userdata.id
        employee_details = Employee.objects.get(id=user_id)
        request.session['user_id'] = employee_details.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/', kwargs={'user_id': employee_details.id}))
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        state = "Username or password incorrect !"
        return render_to_response('login.html',
            {'username' : username1,'state' : state},
            context_instance = RequestContext(request))
else:
    state = "Please login here:"
    return render_to_response('login.html' , {'state' : state} ,
         context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

i tried using kwargs={'user_id': employee_details.id} but it is not working.How can i pass datas to home page after redirecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not redirect user using `POST` request. Use `GET` parameter instead.

In your case the requested data is already stored in session. Just try to read from the session on next request. Django `contrib.auth` uses `user.is_authenticated` method for the job.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried using kwargs={'user_id': employee_details.id} but it is not working.How can i pass datas to home page after redirecting?

You can:

1. use [session variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs)
2. use "get" variables (pass variables encoded in the URL like `'/home/?a=1&b=2'`, see [urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html))

However you should be using the [standard Django user related functions and methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). See "[How to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)". TLDR:

1. check credentials: `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`
2. test if user is not None and any other tests you want (is he active, has some privilege, etc)
3. mark the request.user as authenticated: `login(request, user)`

Comment: Actually am storing these users in a seperate database table.not in django default user table.i have created a table myself as 'portales_employee' and am storing all the details of an employee in that table ie, username password, address,phone no: etc..So i think in this case we can't use authenticate function.we have to do the authentication manually like i did in  my code ie, by comparing username and passwd.(please accept my apology if am wrong).

Comment: See, after authentication i need to pass all other details of an employee such as address,phone no: etc to home page.So like you said, am supposed to pass these details along with URL, like /home/?address=""&phone=""..?is there any simple way like codeigniter, like passing all employee details in an array or something ?so that i can iterate the array in home page?

Comment: I really regret when I tried to reinvent the wheel and made my own authentication instead of using Django's builtin, but you can pass the whole user object in the session or you can pass the user id (in session or URL) and retrieve the other info in the view (or yeat better, using a custom middleware).

Comment: do you mean we can retrieve the user object inside our template? (home.html).